# Perform autologin in background android applications

Tags: android

[image]

THis code can help me create a autologin function after the application is opened. But this cant work in the android 5.1, i try to use this code for replace this, not works well.

```
public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        User user;
        GetUserCallBack userCallBack;

        public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallBack userCallBack){
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallBack = userCallBack;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,SERVER_ADDRESS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                }
            },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("email",user.username);
                    map.put("password",user.password);
                    return map;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            return null;
        }
```

I am not sure this code can help me perform the function. My function actually is like this, the application will first check any email and password store, if yes, then will straight open another activity page and fetch the data from the server.

Comment: `cant work` doesn't say anything. You have to post `logcat` logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put on the user object on sharedpreference then retrieve it. If it exists then I just go to the server and check that data if everything is okay or not. 
You can save object in sharedprefences as well.

After first time login save it with key like customer or user then when next time it comes to the login page check that key and if exists send directly to the place u want.

```
        public boolean saveObjectToLocalDatabase(String key, Object value) {

    String json = gson.toJson(value);
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(commonFunctionMainContext);
    Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString(key, json);
    return prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

To get the object I use a bit primitive but still useful code for me.

```
  public Object getObjectFromLocalDatabase(String key) {

    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(commonFunctionMainContext);
    String json = appSharedPrefs.getString(key, "");
    if (json.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        return null;
    }
    //Customer Data.
    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("customer")) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, Ruhesi_UserObj.class);
    }
    //Customer Data.
    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("ruhesi")) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, Ruhesi_UserObj.class);
    }
    //Customer Data.
    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("chat")) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, Ruhesi_ConversationListObj.class);
    }
    //Customer Data.
    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("chatAdmin")) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, Ruhesi_ConversationListObj.class);
    }
    //Customer Data.
    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Location")) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, Ruhesi_LocationObj.class);
    }
    return null;
}
```

so this way just check what class is that key which you are assigning. If there is better way they can also write here.

Comment: How to save this at the sharedpreference in android 5.1?

Comment: I know it store in the userlocaldatabase, but i not sure how to call out the value that i store in the userlocaldatabase.